# Swift 2.0 migration error with alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, alamofire

I am trying to use this piece of code I got raywenderlich.com in Xcode 7. But at the return line is giving me error saying

> Cannot convert return expression of type `(NilLiteralConvertible,
>   NilLiteralConvertible)` to return type `Result<UIImage>`

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
  public static func imageResponseSerializer() -> GenericResponseSerializer<UIImage> {
    return GenericResponseSerializer { request, response, data in
      if data == nil {
        return (nil, nil)
      }

      let image = UIImage(data: data!, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

      return (image, nil)
    }
  }

  public func responseImage(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, UIImage?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
    return response(responseSerializer: Request.imageResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
  }
}
```

See original code at http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial

Comment: Its difficult to provide an accurate answer because that whole project requires conversion and I don't know how you converted Alamofire's libraries.  For starters I'd try returning a non-optional `UIImage` and see if that works, ideally you'd fix `GenericResponseSerializer` to accept at least a `UIImage?` optional.

Comment: hmm thanks for the answer, but when I set an UIImage as return type xcode is jammed

Comment: @miracle-doh did you get it to work? i am following the same tutorial with swift 2.0 and alamofire 3.0 and i am getting 3 built errors

Comment: yeah, the correct answer is working. I used it like this `Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL).validate(contentType: ["image/*"]).responseImage() {
                (_, _, result) in
                guard let image = result.value else {
                    print("could not fetch image value")
                    return
                }
                //do stuff with `image`
            }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like when you converted your project to Swift 2 you also upgraded to AlamoFire 2.x.  The tutorial was written for Swift 1.2 where the closure's signature was:

```
(NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSData?) -> (SerializedObject?, NSError?)
```

With AlamoFire 2 the signature is now:

```
(NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSData?) -> Result<SerializedObject>
```

This means your method needs to return `.Success(image!)` in the passing condition and `.Failure(data, myError)` in the failing condition.  It also means you can't just pass image without unwrapping since that initializer is nullable and the result's parameter is not.

Your serializer could look something like this:

```
return GenericResponseSerializer { request, response, data in
    guard let validData = data else {
        let error = ...
        return .Failure(data, error)
    }

    guard let image = UIImage(data: validData, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale) else {
        let error = ...
        return .Failure(data, error)
    }

    return .Success(image)
}
```

For your error you could either define your own `ErrorType` enum that will be helpful to you or use `AlamoFire.Error`:

```
let error = Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: "Image parsing failed.")
```

Your `responseImage` function will need a similar change:

```
public func responseImage(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result<UIImage>) -> Void) -> Self {
    return response(responseSerializer: Request.imageResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

This will in turn require you to update code that uses `responseImage` but those error messages should be helpful.

Comment: how do I change the `responseImage` part?

Answer (score 1):

It work for me, remove old Alamofire from Ray's sample, and add last version form git https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire, and change sample XMLResponseSerializer , for UIImage it looks like :

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
public static func imageResponseSerializer() -> ResponseSerializer<UIImage, NSError> {
    return ResponseSerializer { request, response, data, error in
        guard error == nil else { return .Failure(error!) }
        guard let validData = data else {
            let failureReason = "Image parsing failed."
            let error = Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
            return .Failure(error)
        }
        guard let image = UIImage(data: validData, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale) else {
            let failureReason = "Image format failed."
            let error = Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
            return .Failure( error)
        }
        return .Success(image)
    }
}
public func responseImage(completionHandler: Response<UIImage, NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
    return response(responseSerializer: Request.imageResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
}
```